# System.ArgumentException: 'Id field is not correctly populated'

Tags: asp.net-core, redis, stackexchange.redis

I am trying to implement Redis, I am sending a put request from Postman and getting error.

Controller:

```
    [HttpPut]
    [ProducesResponseType((int)HttpStatusCode.Created, Type = typeof(Brand))]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Update([FromBody] Brand brand)
    {
        try
        {
            await _brandCollection.UpdateAsync(brand);
            return Ok();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Error:

> System.ArgumentException: 'Id field is not correctly populated'
> From redis desktop manager I have confirmed that Id exists in record

Postman:

```
{
    "Id": 1,
    "Name": "Xiaomi",
    "IsRegistered": "Yes",
    "About": "Mobile Brand",
    "Countries": [
        "Pakistan",
        "India",
        "China"
    ]
}
```

Brand model class:

```
[Document(StorageType = StorageType.Json, Prefixes = new[] { "Brand" })]
public class Brand
{
        [Indexed] public int Id { get; set; }
        [Indexed] public string? Name { get; set; }
        [Indexed] public string? IsRegistered { get; set; }
        [Indexed] public string? About { get; set; }
        [Indexed] public List<string>? Countries { get; set; }
}
```

I have injected `HostedService` as well in `Program.cs`:

```
builder.Services.AddHostedService<IndexCreationService>();
```

`IndexCreationService`:

```
public class IndexCreationService : IHostedService
{
    private readonly RedisConnectionProvider _provider;

    public IndexCreationService(RedisConnectionProvider provider)
    {
        _provider = provider;
    }

    public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
            await _provider.Connection.CreateIndexAsync(typeof(Person));
            await _provider.Connection.CreateIndexAsync(typeof(Category));
            await _provider.Connection.CreateIndexAsync(typeof(Brand));
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

[RedisIdField][RedisField][Indexed] public int Id { get; set; }

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).